# tengo problemas al crear un formulario responsivo con Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente problema, llevo horas intentando hacer que el formulario se mantenga dentro de un contenedor y que se vaya adaptando a medida que se modifica la resolución de la pantalla pero no he podido lograrlo, incluso he copiado y pegado el código de la pagina oficial de Bootstrap y nada, no se que pasa. Lo que quiero es que se mantenga dentro del contenedor izquierdo y no que sobresalga de este a medida que se reduce la resolución como pasa en la segunda imagen. Espero Puedan ayudarme a identificar que estoy haciendo mal porque no lo veo. Gracias!

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#contenedor-padre{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#contenedor-formulario{
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#columna-izquierda{
    height: 100%;
}

#columna-derecha{
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
    height: 100%;

}

#fila{
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="contenedor-padre"> 
  <div class="row" id="fila">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-6" id="columna-izquierda">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" id="contenedor-formulario">
          
          <form (ngSubmit)="contactForm(form.value)" #form="ngForm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="text-center" id="titulo-formulario">¡Contáctame!</legend>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        
        </div>
      </div>  
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6" id="columna-derecha"> <img src="assets\img\imge.jpg" id="imagen-contacto"> </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

[image: Imagen 3]

Comment: prueba quitando las clases d-flex

Comment: Esta mejor. edite mi pregunta con una nueva imagen de como se ve sin las etiquetas d-flex. Ahora lo que sale del contenedor es la palabra ¡Contactame! que esta dentro de la etiqueta legend, como hago para que se mantenga dentro del contenedor?

Comment: En la clase `.row` estás aplicándole al ID `#fila` un ancho fijo que es el 50% del tamaño del dispositivo, es realmente esto necesario? Puedes aumentarlo a `80vw` para que se ajuste. Podríamos hacer magia tratando de meter la palabra `¡Contáctame!` en ese contenedor, pero si el tamaño es tan pequeño, creo que nos estamos complicando. La otra solución sería disminuir el tamaño de la fuente con `@media querys`

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que quitaste las clases `d-flex` prueba esto:

```
 <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
                <legend class="text-center" id="titulo-formulario">¡Contáctame!</legend>
           </div>
    <div>        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
        </div>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: Sigue igual. se sigue pasando a la columna derecha.